# npm run script resource with relative location of resource

Tags: bash, shell, npm, path, package.json

In my `package.json`, I use

```
"scripts": {
  "install": "Install GettingStarted/Src/Data",
}
```

to install the package with the command `npm run install`

Here, `Install` is an executable bash script, and  `GettingStarted/Src/Data` is the parameter to the bash-script relative to the package location (i.e. location of `package.json`).

Is there any Variable that I could use like `${AbsolutePackagePath}` that I could prefix to my parameter like `${AbsolutePackagePath}/GettingStarted/Src/Data`, such that the bashscript can find the resource.

I don't want to hardcode the absolute path.

Comment: Can't you use `./GettingStarted/...` and have it expanded by the shell?

Comment: I knew that but, then I am constrained to execute it from the path of the package.